# How can I have an object follow a bone but retain its transforms

Tags: bones, parent, transform-orientation

I have a skateboarding animation from Mixamo and I'm trying to attach the skateboard to the foot that isn't pushing.

When I Parent the skateboard to the foot bone it works but there is a small rotation in the foot during the animation that is translating to the skateboard and it is clipping through the surface.

What I want is to move the skateboard as though it's stuck to the foot but keep its original translation.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Try to use copy location constraint

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had been trying to keyframe it but it's time consuming and the results aren't great